# Second Firebase project cant access first project Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an e-commerce website and admin dashboard.

Website using its own hosting, Firestore and authentication.

Admin dashboard own hosting and authentication, but using website Firestore .

The security rules are not letting me in. When I change to admin dashboard project id to the website one, I can access the website Firestore.

I'm thinking that it's know I am coming from the second project that why it didn't allow me to access the website Firestore.

How can I allow second project to access the first project Firestore

```
function authorize() {
    return request.auth != null && 
             request.auth.token.email_verified;
}

function matchOwnID(userID) {
    return request.auth.uid == userID;
}

function authAdmin() {
    return authorize() && 
    exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/admin/$(request.auth.uid));
}


match /admin/{adminID} {
  allow get  : if authAdmin() && matchOwnID(adminID); <--cant access from second project but first project can access.
  // allow get  : if true; <-----can access from second project.
  allow list : if false;
  allow write: if false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I allow second project to access the first project Firestore

You cannot have users authenticated through the Auth service of **one Firebase project** accessing the Firestore database of **an another Firebase project** which has security rules based on the user's authentication state. This is not possible, since you cannot share the [Firebase ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#auth_tokens) across different projects.

---

One solution is to configure the two projects in your app, as explained in the ["Configure multiple projects" doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application).

Then you will be able to login with the two different user accounts corresponding to the two Firebase projects.

For the web, it could be done as follows:

```
  const primaryAppConfig = {
    apiKey: '.....',
    authDomain: '.....',
    // ...
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(primaryAppConfig);

  const secondaryAppConfig = {
    apiKey: '.....',
    authDomain: '.....',
    // ...
  };

  var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(
    secondaryAppConfig,
    'secondary'
  );

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email1, password1)
    .then(() => {
      secondaryApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email2, password2);
    })
    .then(() => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('...')   // Firestore collection from the Primary Project
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
          });
        });

      secondaryApp
        .firestore()
        .collection('...')  // Firestore collection from the Secondary Project
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
          });
        });
    });
```

---

Having said that, are you 100% sure that you need to use the authentication services of the two Firebase Projects? A common approach is to have your main app in a first Firebase Project, using the Auth service of this project. And then use a second Firebase project just for the hosting of the Admin dashboard app. But, in the Admin dashboard app, you point to the first project.

---

Another possible approach is to set up two Firebase Hosting sites in a single Firebase project, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites) for more details.

Comment: i did configure. the configuration of 2 project works

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. So what is the problem then? I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: so i must use the same authentication(first project) to access the same firestore(first project)?

Comment: because both are different website one for customer and one for admin but both need to use the same firestore.

Comment: Yes, the Auth service of each project generates Firebase ID tokens that are only valid for this project.

Comment: "because both are different website one for customer and one for admin but both need to use the same Firestore." => I would recommend having only one Firestore DB in ONE project and use the approaches described at the bottom of my answer if you want to clearly separate the two websites.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226595/discussion-between-phongyewtong-and-renaud-tarnec).

Comment: for the above approach, you cant access the secondary database with security rules if you are using the current project as your authentication. am I right?

Comment: Yes, as said above the Auth service of each project generates Firebase ID tokens that are only valid **for this project**.

Comment: @phongyewtong I just see now your sentence in the chat "I am using 2 auth because admin might use the same login for the customer website." => I think that one interesting possibility would be to set up a role based access right strategy. With Firebase you usually do that through [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). Your admin user would have a "standard user" Custom Claim **PLUS** an Admin Custom Claim.